# Apache log4j and Tomcat 7 DEBUG related logs only logging into "catalina.log" but not only logging into catalina.YYYY-mm-dd.log file

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, log4j

I'm trying to use Apache log4j in Tomcat 7. I need the logs in DEBUG mode so I have used

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
```

I have also used file rolling so as to get the logs daily in a separate file.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

but in the DEBUG mode all the debug related logs are logging into "catalina.out" file instead of the daily created log, I cannot see any DEBUG related logs in the daily created log file only INFO and SEVERE are present in it. And my another question is how to not to log everything into catalina.log file as the file size is keep on increasing

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p     %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Dependencies that I have used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Just a tip. If you are using SLF4J, using XML configuration is much better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in windows environment please add below line code to your File logging configuration:

> log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}\\yourLog.log

This will direct to tomcat->bin folder. If you want specifically in tomcat->logs folder please configure accordingly by going one step backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It is because The Apache Tomcat has a custom version of Log4J (referenced as JULI) built in it.

From the [Tomcat Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html):

> The internal logging for Apache Tomcat uses JULI, a packaged renamed
>   fork of Apache Commons Logging that, by default, is hard-coded to use
>   the java.util.logging framework. This ensures that Tomcat's internal
>   logging and any web application logging will remain independent, even
>   if a web application uses Apache Commons Logging.

You could use:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: This didn't help.. does it resolve seeing debug logs in the daily created log file?

Comment: Where are you putting these settings?

Comment: log4j.properties file

Comment: I mean what are your trying to configure? Your application or the Catalina itself?

Comment: Okay, I edited my example, see if that works out for you... This is a rather strange issue...